# Create instance of a parameterized generic object with all parameters set to null

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, instantiation, activator

Assume a class with a parameterized constructor as:

```
MyObject(string param1, string param2, string param2)
{
   ...
}
```

I have a `Generic` method that returns an instance of the `Generic Class` and 
`MyObject` is one of such instances.

> How can I instantiate a generic class with a parameterized constructor
>   and pass null values to all its parameters? This is needed as
>   properties of the generic class get populated at a slightly later
>   stage.

I have tried using `Activator` as:

```
public static T GetGenericObject<T>()
{
   T resource = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), null); 
   ... 
}
```

But I get exception that I got no parameterless constructor in `MyObject`. I know I could add one easily but the class cannot be modified (don't ask why).

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but it must be said: Requiring properties in a constructor, and then passing null values in because they can be populated later seems like a Really Bad Idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could detect how many parameters there are via reflection, and then pass in null values for each of them in `Activator.CreateInstance()`:

```
var parameters = typeof(T)
    .GetConstructors()
    .Single()
    .GetParameters()
    .Select(p => (object)null)
    .ToArray();
T resource = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameters);
```

Note that this assumes there's only one constructor, and it'll only work for reference types, so it's fairly fragile.

Comment: Great approach! However I get "cannot be inferred from usage.." on .Select(p => null) line

Answer (score 3):

Use the overload that takes parameters and create an object array to pass where null represents each needed parameter.

In light of your comment, you can certainly tell the method to create an initialized but empty object array based on a fixed number of elements.  However, as mentioned in other comments, this is extremely dangerous and will cause you headaches down the road.

```
var instance = GetGenericObject<MyObject>(3);

public static T GetGenericObject<T>(int numberOfNullParametersToPass)
{
    var nullParams = new object[numberOfNullParametersToPass];
    T resource = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), nullParams); 
    return resource;
}
```

As your code currently stands, you are explicitly telling `Activator.CreateInstance` to choose the parameterless constructor.  By specifying all three arguments (even though they are null), you are selecting the correct constructor.

At some point in the call chain you need to tell `Activator.CreateInstance` which constructor to choose.  An alternative is to choose the first possible constructor.

```
public static T GetGenericObject<T>()
{
    var paramLength = typeof(T).GetConstructors().FirstOrDefault().GetParameters().Length;
    var parameters = new object[paramLength]; 
    T resource = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameters); 
    return resource;
}
```

Comment: @eYe: are you positive that all the parameters will always be reference types? Could any of them be an `int`, e.g.?

Comment: I should have mentioned that, my mistake, parameters can only be strings or DateTime, so yes, all are reference types.

Comment: @eYe: DateTime is not a reference type--it is a value type, so you cannot pass `null` to it. What value would you want to pass in for a DateTime parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Below is simple method without worring about parameter and avoid error of no default construtor exists

```
var ctors = typeof(T).GetConstructors();
var ctor = ctors[0];
var instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[ctor.GetParameters().Length]);
```

Comment: Tried that too -> NullRef exception